# Tensorflow installation through Anaconda, error

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have been trying to install Tensorflow(CPU only) on ubuntu 14.0.5 (64bit) through Anaconda. I have been following this page [a link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingAnaconda)!
I have python 3.6.1. However, I have not managed to install it and receive following error.

> tensorflow-1.3.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Any solution to this issue?

Comment: try `conda install tensorflow`

Comment: @Straw I have tried it gives following;                                         < PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current linux-32 channels: 
  - tensorflow

Close matches found; did you mean one of these?

    tensorflow: r-tensorflow

Comment: It seems you installed a 32bit anaconda on 64bit linux. Try reinstall 64bit anaconda.

Comment: I have changed that to 64bit anaconda. When I install I get this error,              Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zawan/new/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/zawan/new/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easy_install.py'

Comment: Did you install anaconda use `sudo`? For example, `sudo bash Anaconda.sh`

Comment: @Straw, I have finally installed by using conda install tensorflow. Thanks,